# Case sensitivity check constraint with LIKE operator using character range wildcards

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-sensitive, sql-like, check-constraints

I'm facing a problem in regular expressions case sensitivity. In a regular expression expression only the first item works within the square brackets.

```
create table
(
    FlowerId varchar(7)

    constraint chk_flid_regex 
    check(ActorId like'[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]' collate sql_latin1_general_CP1_CS_AS)
);
```

Eg. If i give something like this
'[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]'
Only the first [A-Z] is checked by the server. The third [A-Z] is not checked.

So if I insert values like 'Abc' gets inserted while it shouldn't actually get inserted into the table. Whereas, it doesn't give any error. It should only accept characters like 'AbC'.

Comment: That is kinda funky. I would have expected the case-sensitivy collation would have made it work. Another way you could also do it is build a check statement on the three characters your care about and make sure individually they're within the allowable characters. something like ascii(substring(actorId, 1, 1)) between 97 and 122

Answer (score 3):

Though I can't explain why the CS collation isn't working, switching to a binary collation seems to behave as you are expecting, at least with Sql Server 2008:

```
create table tbl
(
     FlowerId varchar(7)
constraint chk_flid_regex 
check(FlowerId like'[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]' collate Latin1_General_BIN)
);
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91ff1/4/1)

Comment: Yes, using a binary collation (`_BIN` or `_BIN2`) is the way to solve this. The reason has to do with the concept of dictionary ordering as opposed to strict equality when filtering on ranges. I have provided a thorough explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176370/why-does-filtering-on-a-range-match-the-wrong-case-when-using-a-case-sensitive-c/26185647#26185647 +1. And please see the example I am leaving in a comment on Damien's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the range form, you have to expand out all the letters you want to use:

```
create table
(
    FlowerId varchar(7)

    constraint chk_flid_regex 
    check(ActorId like'[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]' collate sql_latin1_general_CP1_CS_AS)
);
```

Or switch to a binary collation. Why? Because in most collations, the lower case letters are placed between the upper case letters, either before or after their upper case equivalents. So the range `A-Z` expands out as `AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZ` - all you've excluded as a letter is lower-case `z`.

---

(I hope I've got my alphabet right each time I've had to type it out above, but you might want to check carefully that I've not missed out any letters)

Comment: Well, yes and no ;-). The SQL Server collation you are using actually sorts capitals first. But, the windows collation of "Latin1_General_CS_AS" does sort lower-case first. Test with the following: `SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' LIKE '[A-C]' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
SELECT 2 WHERE 'a' LIKE '[ABC]' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
SELECT 3 WHERE 'A' LIKE '[a-c]' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
SELECT 4 WHERE 'a' LIKE '[A-C]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
SELECT 5 WHERE 'A' LIKE '[a-c]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;` You should only get "1" and "5" being returned.

Comment: Just re-read @srutzky's comment. I think it should be `AaBb...YyZ` for `sql_latin1_general_CP1_CS_AS`. (Because, as his tests show, `'a'` falls between `'A'` and `'C'`, so it can't go before `'A'`.) And while we are at it, your alphabet is fine, except the lower-case sequence's got an extra zed.

Comment: @AndriyM - cheers. It's amazing how you can look at these things tens or hundreds of times and still not spot the obvious.

Answer (score -1):

```
^[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]$
```

Add anchors to disallow partial matches.

Comment: This answer is entirely irrelevant to the question. The title was (until I just fixed it) admittedly misleading, but reading the question should have made it very clear that this is not about RegEx but instead about a SQL LIKE operator that does not support anchors. Though, even if this was a question about Regular Expressions, this answer would still be wrong given that the O.P. states that `Abc` is matching and this has nothing to do with partial matches. -1